# Drawing a Circle in VB.NET with given Size and X/Y POS producing unexpected results

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, 2d, system.drawing

I'm making an application that draws a circle when given the inputs of the Diameter and the Center Point of the Circle's `X` and `Y` via. a `TextBox` inside a PictureBox.

When I run the application and put in a constant X and Y but slowly increase/decrease the diameter of the circle, the circle starts randomly moving in position even though the X and Y positions are constant. Sometimes, if I refresh the `PictureBox` when any of the variables were not changed (X Pos, Y Pos, and Diameter), the circles moves for no reason at all even though nothing was changed...

This is code to reproduce:

These variables were already declared:

```
    Dim beginSCircleXPos As Integer 'What the user put into as the circle's center for X
    Dim beginSCircleYPos As Integer 'What the user put into as the circle's center for y

    Dim sCircleXPos As Integer 'Top-Left point of the circle in X
    Dim sCircleYPos As Integer 'Top-Left point of the circle in Y
    Dim sCircleDiameter As Integer 'The diameter that user put into.


    Dim sCenterPointX As Integer 'Variables will be updated later
    Dim sCenterPointY As String
```

`PictureBox`'s `Paint` event

```
beginSCircleXPos = TextBox1.Text
        beginSCircleYPos = TextBox2.Text

        sCircleXPos = beginSCircleXPos - sCircleDiameter / 2
        sCircleYPos = beginSCircleYPos - sCircleDiameter / 2


        sCircleDiameter = TextBox3.Text


        Using path As New GraphicsPath
            path.AddEllipse(sCircleXPos, sCircleYPos, sCircleDiameter, sCircleDiameter)
            sCenterPointX = sCircleXPos + sCircleDiameter / 2
            sCenterPointY = sCircleYPos + sCircleDiameter / 2

            Using brush As New PathGradientBrush(path)
                brush.CenterPoint = New PointF(sCenterPointX, sCenterPointY) 
                brush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Orange)
                brush.SurroundColors = {Color.Orange}
                brush.FocusScales = PointF.Empty

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, sCircleXPos, sCircleYPos, sCircleDiameter, sCircleDiameter)
            End Using
        End Using
```

It is worth noting that the `PictureBox` is refreshed by clicking a button with the `PictureBox1.Refresh()` command.

How can I fix this so that the Input of the Center Point and the X/Y values will result in a correct and constant answer every time?

**EDIT:**

````
  beginSCircleXPos = Convert.ToSingle(TextBox1.Text)
        beginSCircleYPos = Convert.ToSingle(TextBox2.Text)


        sCircleXPos = beginSCircleXPos - sCircleDiameter / 2
        sCircleYPos = beginSCircleYPos - sCircleDiameter / 2


        sCircleDiameter = Convert.ToSingle(TextBox3.Text)






        Using path As New GraphicsPath
            path.AddEllipse(sCircleXPos, sCircleYPos, sCircleDiameter, sCircleDiameter)
            sCenterPointX = sCircleXPos + sCircleDiameter / 2
            sCenterPointY = sCircleYPos + sCircleDiameter / 2

            Using brush As New PathGradientBrush(path)
                brush.CenterPoint = New PointF(sCenterPointX, sCenterPointY) 
                brush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Orange)
                brush.SurroundColors = {Color.Orange}
                brush.FocusScales = PointF.Empty

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, sCircleXPos, sCircleYPos, sCircleDiameter, sCircleDiameter)
            End Using
        End Using
    ```
Variables:
````

Dim beginSCircleXPos As Single
Dim beginSCircleYPos As Single

```
Dim sCircleXPos As Single
Dim sCircleYPos As Single
Dim sCircleDiameter As Single


Dim sCenterPointX As Single
Dim sCenterPointY As Single
```

Comment: You should start by turning `Option Strict On` and addressing the issues it flags. Turn it `On` in the project properties and also in the Vs options, so it will be `On` by default in future projects. I don't know if it is the root of your specific problem but you are playing fast and loose with data types there, which `Option Strict On` will prevent. If that doesn't fix the issue, post your improved code and we can take another look.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Edited Code, No improvement on result. Please take a look at it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look too closely at your code. I still had the code that I provided to answer your previous question so I used that as a basis and just modified it as I would do it myself. I used a `Timer` to repaint the `PictureBox` once every second to make it a bit simpler. This is what I ended up with:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim centreX As Single
    Dim centreY As Single
    Dim diameter As Single

    If Single.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, centreX) AndAlso
       Single.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, centreY) AndAlso
       Single.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, diameter) Then
        Dim radius = diameter / 2.0F
        Dim bounds As New RectangleF(centreX - radius,
                                     centreY - radius,
                                     diameter,
                                     diameter)

        Using path As New GraphicsPath
            path.AddEllipse(bounds)

            Using brush As New PathGradientBrush(path) With {.CenterPoint = New PointF(centreX, centreY),
                                                             .CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Orange),
                                                             .SurroundColors = {Color.Orange},
                                                             .FocusScales = PointF.Empty}
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds)
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

It seemed to work just as expected for me. If one or more of the `TextBoxes` didn't contain a valid number then nothing was drawn, otherwise a graded circle was drawn where and how expected. If I set the centre coordinates and then varied the diameter, the circle that was drawn maintained a constant centre but grew and shrunk as expected.

You can obviously use a `Button.Click` instead of a `Timer.Tick` if you want.